# What is the optimal way to search for value density in a given matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, matrix

Suppose I have an `n:n` matrix with `short` - only positive - values in it like this:

```
0 1 0 3
1 0 5 6
7 1 0 4
6 2 7 9
```

I'm searching for an `m:m` matrix within this one which contains the most values which are greater than 0. My problem is that the solution I have so far does not scale well with `n` (nor `m`).

In fact the `n:n` matrix represents prices of a product and the axes are representing days from a given (arbitrary) day. So you can search for prices in a given time interval. The `m:m` matrix is in fact a 7 x 7 matrix which contains a subset (like a view) of the prices. I'm looking for the part of the `n:n` matrix where I have the most prices filled in.

In the example above the `m:m` matrix is

```
7 1
6 2
```

where `m` is 2.

Here are the relevant parts of the prototype I have written so far:

```
private static class ResultMatrixData {
    private byte fillCount;
    private short distanceFromToday;

    public ResultMatrixData() {
        fillCount = 0;
        distanceFromToday = Short.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public ResultMatrixData(short[][] pricesMatrix, short iArg, short jArg) {
        byte fillCount = 0;
        for (int i = iArg; i < iArg + 7; i++) {
            for (int j = jArg; j < jArg + 7; j++) {
                if (pricesMatrix[i][j] > 0) {
                    fillCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        this.fillCount = fillCount;
        distanceFromToday = iArg > jArg ? iArg : jArg;
    }
}

private ResultMatrixData calculateSingleResult(short[][] pricesMatrix) {
    ResultMatrixData bestSoFar = new ResultMatrixData();
    ResultMatrixDataComparator comparator = new ResultMatrixDataComparator();
    for (short i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_DAYS - 6; i++) {
        for (short j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_DAYS - 6; j++) {
            ResultMatrixData current = new ResultMatrixData(pricesMatrix, i, j);
            if (comparator.compare(current, bestSoFar) >= ResultMatrixDataComparator.GREATER_THAN) {
                bestSoFar = current;
            }
        }
    }
    return bestSoFar;
}

private static class ResultMatrixDataComparator implements Comparator<ResultMatrixData> {
    private static final int LESS_THAN = -1;
    private static final int EQUAL = 0;
    private static final int GREATER_THAN = 1;

    @Override
    public int compare(ResultMatrixData first, ResultMatrixData second) {
        if (first.fillCount > second.fillCount) {
            return GREATER_THAN;
        } else if (first.fillCount < second.fillCount) {
            return LESS_THAN;
        } else {
            if (first.distanceFromToday < second.distanceFromToday) {
                return GREATER_THAN;
            } else if (first.distanceFromToday > second.distanceFromToday) {
                return LESS_THAN;
            }
        }
        return EQUAL;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the running time seems quadratic or exponential (I did not perform accurate asymptotic analysis):

```
n (days)  | running time in ms 
1 *  365  | 48
2 *  365  | 123
3 *  365  | 278
4 *  365  | 482
5 *  365  | 733
6 *  365  | 1069
7 *  365  | 1438
8 *  365  | 1890
9 *  365  | 2383
10 * 365  | 2926
11 * 365  | 3646
12 * 365  | 4208
13 * 365  | 5009
```

Do you have any suggestions how can I optimize this algoritm?

*Note: this is not a homework exercise.*

**Edit:** As others said in their answers the time complexity here is around O((`n`-`m`)^2). I'm searching for something which is sub-quadratic and which does scale well while `n` converges to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, if speaking about the worst case scenario when computing the complexity, you cannot do better than O((m-n)^2), which is actually O(n^2) if n is not larger that C*m, when C is some positive constant.
The reason is that even if you knew that the only possible matrices are all zeroes except in once cell, in worst case, you cannot answer the question without going through all the cells of the m:m matrix except for n^2 cells.

I would suggest the following algorithm, which can even give more options than asked.

1. Create a matrix A of the same size as the original matrix M, in which the cell (i,j) will hold the number of non-zeros at the rectangle between (0,0).
   You can fill it simply by going through the rows from right to left one by one, and calculate:
   **A(i,j)=A(i-1,j)+ (A(i,j-1)-A(i-1,j-1)) + (M(i,j) != 0 )**.
   Or instead of (A(i,j-1)-A(i-1,j-1)) you can have counter of number of ones you encountered in the i-the row by now.
   In this pseudo code A(0,j) or A(i,0) means 0, assuming that the indices start from 1.
2. Now you can query in O(1) the number of non-zeroes in every triangular sub-matrix M((i,j)(l,k)) of M, including the n:n matrices (and as already mentioned, you have (m-n)^2 of them:
   **num_of_non-zeros in M((i,j)(l,k)) = A(l,k)-A(l,j)-A(i,k)+A(i,j)**

Notice that you can combine 1 and 2 to the same double loop and check for the number of non-zero values of the n:n sub-matrix M((i-n,j-n)(i,j)) right after computing A(i,j).

So you get a quadratic simple algorithm, which could be easily extended to other similar applications.

Comment: I ended up implementing something like this. Since I did not bother answering my own question I'll accept yours. So in short I could only flatten the quadratic curve but it won me enough time for the next 100 years. :D

Comment: Good :)
But I'm not sure that I would even call the solution quadratic, because it's **linear to the size of the input**, which is a m:m matrix.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 pieces of data you dont use enough:

1. youre keeping your "best" result anyway. you can break out of a specific "rectangle" youre evaluating if it couldnt possibly beat your current "best" (so if youve already seen a 2x2 with 3 non-zero elements and you just hit your 2nd zero evaluating a certain rectangle you can break out of it
2. you also know the max possible count for a rectangle = mxm (so 4 in your care). the minute you find a rectangle with 4 non-zeros you can break the whole thing - its the best you could possibly get.

non of these suggestions is an algorithmic improvement though.

you could try a "scanning window" approach:
1.starting at 0,0, calculate the score for the "top left" mxm window using a full scan as you do now.

1. scan right by one column - take your score, substract the score for the left-most (lowest index) column, and add the score for the neighbouring column to the right.
2. proceed with step 2 until you reach the end of the row, then scan downward one row (substract the scores for your top row, add those for the row below you
3. progress "left" (toward lower column indexes) until you reach the edge, at which point scan down one undex and start heading right again (step 2).

this will save you some recalculations if m is large. just to demonstrate the iteration order of this algorithm, this is scanning a 3x3 rectangle out of a 7x7 "board":

```
    going right -->        hitting the edge, moving     hit edge, go down     etc
                          down one row, heading left        head right
xxx.... .xxx... ..xxx..     ....xxx ....... .......     ....... .......     .......
xxx.... .xxx... ..xxx..     ....xxx ....xxx ...xxx.     xxx.... .......     .......
xxx.... .xxx... ..xxx..     ....xxx ....xxx ...xxx.     xxx.... xxx....     ....xxx
....... ....... ....... ... ....... ....xxx ...xxx. ... xxx.... xxx.... ... ....xxx
....... ....... .......     ....... ....... .......     ....... xxx....     ....xxx
....... ....... .......     ....... ....... .......     ....... .......     .......
....... ....... .......     ....... ....... .......     ....... .......     .......
```

this way i only "calculate" 6 elements instead of 9 each time i move to the next rectangle - the edges. the benefit grows larger the larger your m is.

**parallelizing this**

you can scan every "row" as a separate task (across multiple cores and even machines).

```
      Task 1        |        Task 2       |        Task N
xxx....     ....xxx | .......     ....... | .......     .......
xxx....     ....xxx | xxx....     ....xxx | .......     .......
xxx.... --> ....xxx | xxx.... --> ....xxx | ....... --> .......
.......     ....... | xxx....     ....xxx | xxx....     ....xxx
.......     ....... | .......     ....... | xxx....     ....xxx
.......     ....... | .......     ....... | xxx....     ....xxx
```

then you just need to pick the best result out of the the results returned by each task (each task returns the best result for its row)

**theoretical bounds:**
for m being the size of the "window" and M being the size of the board, there are (M-m)x(M-m) such windows, and the worst case scenario involves going over all of them.
so i dont *think* you can avoid the O(n^2) curve here. you can just play around with the coefficient

Comment: That's what I thought :(

Comment: @AdamArold - dont despair :-) for 7x7 windows my scanning approach does 14 calculations per window instead of 49, which means it might be up to 3 times faster than your original approach, and x6 times faster for n=13

Comment: It seems so far that we are not planning to search for an interval bigger than 365 but it is possible that I will need to extend it to a decade (10 * 365) or more.

Comment: ...how about multi-threading? can you maybe use that? slices in parallel? maybe even on multiple machines?

Comment: I'm thinking about a solution involving bitvectors since I don't really care about the prices but their existance which can be represented by bitvectors.

Comment: it'll save you memory but not complexity (i think). on the MT front, you could easily turn a MxM problem into (M-m) parallel tasks and then just find the best result out of those, so while i dont think you can beat O(M^2) the solution could be easily distributed across macny cores/machines

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll work out another soution involving a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

from the question i assume the following: find the maximal (nxn) submatrice B_{i,j} in A, which contains the least number of zeros

if this is correct:

1. calculate (or guess) the maximal element which occures in the matrix, and take it's negate, name this value as: POISON
2. go thru all elements of A and POISON the non desired numbers (<=0)
3. calculate the full prefix of each row (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)

   ```
   y_0=x_0;
   for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
   y_i=y_{i-1}+x_i
   ```

   }
4. apply the following on the all row's prefixes:

   x_i = x_i - x_{i-m}

   *drop the first 'm-1' elements*
5. the row prefixes are forming a matrix, translate it (you can work around this depending on your implementation, but if you do, the implementation would be more complex)
6. repeat step 3 on step 5's matrix
7. repeat step 4 on step 6's output
8. find the maximal element in the matrix...if it's at (i,j) then in the original matrix: starting from (j,i) there would be the maximal sumbatrix

complexity based on A's size(n): O(n*n)

Comment: This is actually worse than the O((n-m)^2) algorithm what I already have.

Comment: your input matrix has size n*n, you can't be below n*n because you must read the input...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all how far you could go with such approach, but here we go:
I would try to swap rows and columns so as to move the zeroes away from top left.
Thus resulting matrix m:m will be found at top left.

We need to evaluate if it's interesting to swap rows/columns.
For this, we build a cost function based on this matrix of weights:

```
 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
 6 6 5 4 3 2 1
 5 5 5 4 3 2 1
 4 4 4 4 3 2 1
 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

In other words, the weight of row i, column j (0-based) is min(n-i,n-j).

Each 0 found costs corresponding weight and we want to minimize the total cost.
A swap is interesting if it reduces total cost.

In order to reduce evaluation costs, We could use a kind of structure for sparse matrix:

- map zeros positions per row, that is a collection of (columnIndex) for each rowIndex
- map zeros positions per column, that is a collection of (rowIndex) for each columnIndex

We now have a problem of sorting rows and columns.
A sub-optimal approach would consist in solving sub-problems separately:

- swap rows,
- swap columns,
- iterate until the costs does not evolve.

There is an advantage in swapping two rows i and k if:

```
weigth.atRow(i).sumOfIndices(zerosPerRow.at(i)) + weigth.atRow(k).sumOfIndices(zerosPerRow.at(k)) >
weigth.atRow(i).sumOfIndices(zerosPerRow.at(k)) + weigth.atRow(k).sumOfIndices(zerosPerRow.at(i))
```

Note that this is not a full order-relationship, so not all sorting algorithm will succeed.

Maybe there is an interest in reducing even more combinatorial with additional heuristics: swap lines with most zeroes to the bottom, column with most zeroes to the right.

Obviously, lines/columns with full rank don't need to be sorted once moved up/left.

So maybe that sorting subset of lines/columns of same rank is a reasonnably (sub-)optimal algorithm.

Comment: I have no use for weights and the values need to be in place. I don't get what are you trying to achieve with this approach (apart from a sub-optimal algorithm).

Comment: @AdamArold the purpose is to reduce both evaluation costs by using appropriate sparse structure and combinatorials by using possibly sub-optimal heuristics. Since you create a sparse structure, you just swap this artefact, not the original matrix. Once correctly sorted, you have the answer for m=1, m=2, ... m=n-1.

Comment: @AdamArold the weights are here just to correctly sort rows/columns, not for any other use

Comment: @AdamArold does the submatrix have to be contiguous?

Comment: What do you mean by "contiguous"?

Comment: @AdamArold here is a non contiguous submatrix extracted from your 4x4 example, take rows (0,2) and columns (1,3) to form submatrix [1 3; 1 4]